# How to run program through command line from .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to run a program, say "robocopy.exe", through an aspx page using the System.Diagnostics.Process object.

My code looks like this:

```
Process si = new Process();
si.StartInfo.UserName = "testuser";
si.StartInfo.Password = password;
si.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
si.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;       

si.StartInfo.Arguments = "c/ robocopy.exe";

si.Start();
string output = si.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
si.Close();

Label1.Text = output;
```

The problem is that the cmd.exe process is started correctly, but nothing happens. The argument of roboxopy.exe is presumably not passed to the cmd process to run! Any ideas as to what Icould be doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to run cmd.exe? Why not run robocopy.exe directly? Pass the path to robocopy to your StartInfo.FileName instead of cmd.exe.

Comment: You should probably also write `/c` instead of `c/` if you want to call this executable from `cmd`.

Comment: You Need to have a Dedicated Server and Configure it to run an exe file or execute a command!

Comment: Haha, I think Yuriy was correct in that it should be /c not c/!!! I will take MAtt's suggestion into consideration, as well, though.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a permission issue.  Usually the default asp_net account that any IIS processes run under will not have execute permissions on the server.  The reason that this is the case is because it is a huge security hole.  I would highly recommend that you think about what you are trying to accomplish and see if there is another way to do it that does not involve running a separate executable.